# How to minimize a string's length by iteratively removing all occurrences of some specified words from the string

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, substring

This question appeared in a programming contest and we still have no idea how to solve it.

Question:
Given a string S and a list of strings L, we want to keep removing all occurences of substrings that may be in L. And we have to minimize the length of the final string formed. Also note that removal of a string may initiate more removals.

For example,

1. S=ccdedefcde,  L={cde}
   then answer = 1. Because we can reduce S by ccdedefcde -> cdefcde -> fcde -> f.
2. S=aabaab, L={aa, bb} then answer = 0 as reduction can be carried out by aabaab -> aabb -> aa -> ‘Empty String’
3. S=acmmcacamapapc, L={mca, pa} then answer=6 as reduction can be carried out by acmmcacamapapc-> acmcamapapc -> acmapapc -> acmapc.

The maximum length of S can be 50 and the maximum length of list L can be 50.

My approach is a basic recursive traversal in which I return the minimum length that I can get by removing different sub-strings. Unfortunately this recursive approach will time out in the worst case input as we have 50 options at each step and the recursion depth is 50.

Please suggest an efficient algorithm that may solve this problem.

Comment: You can speed up a basic recursive depth first search for this problem by maintaining a set of the reduced strings encountered so far. When you see one of these again return instead of repeating the recursion from that string.

Comment: This problem is hard: a greedy leftmost-deletion algorithm can fail even for a problem instance with |L|=1. S=ABABAA, L={ABA}. Leftmost-greedy will delete [ABA]BAA to leave BAA, which can't be reduced further. But if you delete AB[ABA]A to get ABA, you can then delete [ABA] to get the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a polynomial-time algorithm that yields optimal results. Since it's convenient for me, I'm going to use the polynomial-time [CYK algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm) as a subroutine, specifically the extension that computes a minimum-weight parse of a string according to a context-free grammar with weighted productions.

Now we just have to formalize this problem with a context-free grammar. The start symbol is `A` (usually `S`, but that's taken already), with the following productions.

```
A -> N      (weight 0)
A -> A C N  (weight 0)
```

I'll explain `N` shortly. If `N` and `C` were terminals, then `A` would accept the regular language `N (C N)*`. The nonterminal `C` matches a single terminal (character).

```
C -> a  (weight 1)
C -> b  (weight 1)
C -> c  (weight 1)
...
```

The nonterminal `N` matches strings that are *nullable*, that is, strings that can be reduced to the empty string by deleting strings in `L`. The base case is obvious.

```
N ->                (weight 0)
```

We also have a production for each element of `L`. When `L = {mca, pa}`, for example, we have the following productions.

```
N -> N m N c N a N  (weight 0)
N -> N p N a N      (weight 0)
```

I hope that it's clear how to construct the one-to-one correspondence between iterative removals and parses, where the parse weight is equal to the length of the residual string.

Comment: (CYK is hiding a ternarization process and one of the cubic all-intervals dynamic programs.)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: this is not an optimal solution, since it doesn't work for the example* `S=ABAABABAA, L={ABA}`

**Algorithm**

```
RECURSIVE_FUNCTION ( STRING STR, STRING PATTERN) :

1. STRING LEFT = STR.SUBSTR (0, STR.FIND(PATTERN))

2. STRING RIGHT = STR.SUBSTR(STR.FIND(PATTERN), STR.LENGTH)

3. IF (RIGHT is empty) THEN RETURN LEFT

4. STRING FIN = RECUR(LEFT) + RECUR(RIGHT)

5. RETURN RECUR(FIN)
```

**function** `SUBSTR(A,B)` will return substring of the string, from index A inclusive to index B exclusive

**Operation** `A + B` is concatenation of string A and B

**function** `RECUR(A)` call the same function, aka recurrence

---

**Example: ccdedefcde**

First it will branch down with `RECUR(LEFT) + RECUR(RIGHT)`:

```
c[cde]defcde
  /    \
 c     def[cde]
       /
      def
```

Then it will `RECUR(FIN)` on merge:

```
  cdef*
  /  \
 c   def
     /
    def
```

* will RECUR to do the following before that MERGE completes:

```
  [cde]f
       \
        f
```

and finally the ROOT call returns `f`

Comment: There is a set of patterns, not just one.

Comment: What makes it hard is that deleting substrings greedily, as you do here, can fail: e.g. a greedy strategy fails with S=AABABABAA, L={ABA, AABBAA}.  If you try to delete the leftmost ABA you get ABABAA, which can be further reduced to BAA; but if you skip over it and delete the next one, you get AABBAA, which can be reduced to the empty string on the next step.

Comment: In fact, here's a problem instance with an L set of size just 1 that still fails using your leftmost-greedy deletion algorithm: S=ABAABABAA, L={ABA}.  Your algorithm deletes [ABA]ABABAA to get ABABAA, then deletes [ABA]BAA to leave BAA, which can't be reduced further.  But if you delete ABA[ABA]BAA to get ABABAA, then delete AB[ABA]A to get ABA, then a third step could reduce the string to the empty string.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The question did not ask for an optimal algorithm, I did not say that my algorithm is optimal, thus my answer is valid

Comment: @j_random_hacker You have shown a good example which shows that my algorithm is not optimal, if you have a better algorithm you can post that, I will update my solution if I can make it better, thank you

Comment: Unless the question **doesn't** ask for the optimal solution, it's usually assumed that the question is looking for it. Not to mention that this is for a programming contest, where optimal solutions are expected by default. If you're not giving an optimal solution, you should **clearly indicate that** (in the answer).

Comment: @Dukeling noted in the post